# Convert data frame with following format into time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data set as follows for the rainfall received by Karnataka. How can I convert it into a time series format in R?

[image: Dataset example]

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyr` and `zoo`, this only takes a few steps. If you also load `dplyr`, you can pipe it. Assuming your table is called `df`...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
    # use tidyr to convert the wide data to long
    gather(key = month, value = value, -Year) %>%
    # use zoo to create a year-month index
    mutate(yearmon = as.yearmon(paste(month, Year))) %>%
    # now make a zoo object of the values with that index
    with(., zoo(value, order.by = yearmon))
```